# Prepopulating a select input fields in an update form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am creating an update form for data in my php/mysql application. To prepopulate the values of an input type="text" field in the update form from existing data, i am using this code:

```
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input name="username" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>">
```

This code above successfully displays the existing data from the database for editing.
However, for a select dropdown input field that dynamically creates select options as in the code below, how do I redisplay the existing selected data in an update form?

```
<label for="user_role">User Role:</label>
<select name="user_role">
   <option value="">Select User Role</option>
<?php
   // get results
   $query = 'SELECT userid, user_role FROM users_profile ORDER BY user_role';
   $results = $conn->query($query);
   while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {?>
   <option value="<?php echo $row['user_role']; ?>"  <?php if (isset($_POST['userid']) &&     in_array($row['user_role'], $_POST['user_role'])) {echo 'selected';
   } ?>><?php echo $row['user_role']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <label for="user_role">User Role:</label>
    <select name="user_role">
       <option value="">Select User Role</option>
    <?php
       // get results
       $query = 'SELECT userid, user_role FROM users_profile ORDER BY user_role';
       $results = $conn->query($query);
       while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
           $selected='';
           if($row['user_role']==$update_id['user_role']) // put your update user_role here
           $selected='selected="selected"';
           ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $row['user_role']; ?>" <?php  echo $selected; ?>><?php echo $row['user_role']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```